# Use string in RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, image, backgroundworker

Alright, So I've tried and tried to look around for a solution to this, but I've had no luck. I'd really appreciate some help here. I've got the following string I want to access within my RunWorkerCompleted, but I'm not sure how or why it isn't able to access it.

```
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("link\":\"(.*?)\"");
            Match match = reg.Match(result);
            string url = match.ToString().Replace("link\":\"", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("\\/", "/");
            return url;
```

So that string is inside of a public object I've delcared as UploadImage

I'm trying to access it in my RunWorker Completed so my textbox returns the Image URL.

Here is my Background Worker -

```
     private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
           string url = UploadImage(FilePath) as string;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtUploaded.Text = (url);
//unknown error in string url as it isn't accessible...
            if (txtUploaded.Text != null)
            {

                Clipboard.Clear();
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(txtUploaded.Text, true, 5, 100);

            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
```

Any help on being able to use that string to set my textbox to the returned image url would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `url` is defined and only accessible in the background thread.

The BackgroundWorker mechanism provides a safe way to pass data from your background thread back to the UI thread.

---

Assign the value to the result in your `DoWork` event:

```
e.Result = UploadImage(FilePath) as string;
```

Then read it out in your `RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
string url = (string)e.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) Sorry about this all. It's been a long day of debugging.